# Windows 7 won't reduce fan speed

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, fan, cooling

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, and I have an [Asus M2N-X](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2NX/) motherboard and an [AMD Athlon 64 X2](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/processors/athlon-x2/Pages/amd-athlon-x2-dual-core-processors-desktop.aspx). If I do something, what is raise the temperature, the OS raise also the fan speed.
It will stop about 3,3k RPM.

If the temperature has reduced, it won't reduce the speed of the fan to slower RPM. I can solve that problem if I send it to sleep mode, and wake it up...

Can it somehow do it automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: My BIOS is up to date. How can I make it sure, that this is not a BIOS bug?

Comment: Make sure you cooler is clean. Try to spin it see if it spins smoothly.

Comment: I have just replaced them last summer, they were new, and they behaved the same (also the olders the same)... and they spin smoothly.